# Name Conversion

Tags: mysql

I have a stored procedure in a table where column name is coming in the parameter as string - varchar

I need to convert this to a column name to query in the select/insert/update as column name should be colnName

How to convert the incoming string to column name in stored procedure..Any function or way to do this

Thanks

Comment: Dynamic SQL ([Prepared Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html)) is the only option.

Comment: Dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54715234/passing-a-column-name-as-parameter-to-a-stored-procedure-in-mysql

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use that string directly.  However, you can 'construct' the desire SQL statement with `CONCAT`, then `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE` the result.

Comment: How about this @Rick James - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54715234/passing-a-column-name-as-parameter-to-a-stored-procedure-in-mysql

Comment: @dolphinkens This is useful link. Apply. The only point - for the parameter which receives an object name (table name) the definition VARCHAR(100) is excess, VARCHAR(64) is enough.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74202350/how-to-convert-the-string-parameter-to-a-column-name/74208478#74208478